# How do I update localStorage items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, local

I'm having a problem where the cached object doesn't resemble the correct data so I figured it I can push up the most uptodate version to the browser cache it will solve my problem.

How do you update your localStorage with a new object? So if I had a controller with that had an assessment updated. How can I push that assessment object up to the localStorage?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem()` shouldn't work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do that with native JavaScript, you would do something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('itemKey', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemKey'));
```

Within the context of angular, you should make a localStorage service as a wrapper around localStorage and inject it into your service or controller. Or you could inject `$window` and use it directly off of that like: `$window.localStorage`

Answer (score 4):

A response specifically for the asker of [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155249/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-item-in-localstorage-using-javascript):

LocalStorage can only store strings, which is why you're stringifying your object before storing it. To manipulate the stored string as an object, you can pass it to `JSON.parse` (assuming it's properly JSON-formatted). Then to store the modified version, you need to convert it back into a string.

```
// Creates JSON-formatted object, converts it to a string and stores the string as "ship"
const ship = { name: "black pearl", captain: "Jack Sparrow" };
const originalStringifiedForStorgage = JSON.stringify(ship);
localStorage.setItem("ship", JSON.stringify(ship));

// Retrieves the string and converts it to a JavaScript object 
const retrievedString = localStorage.getItem("ship");
const parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedString);

// Modifies the object, converts it to a string and replaces the existing `ship` in LocalStorage
parsedObject.name = "newName";
const modifiedndstrigifiedForStorage = JSON.stringify(parsedObject);
localStorage.setItem("ship", strigifiedForStorage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object is in JSON format (not sure if Angular uses a different format) you could probably use the `setItem()` and `getItem()` methods to update and retrieve local storage items!

For example taken from the following post:
http://thejackalofjavascript.com/storing-objects-html5-local-storage/

```
var me = {name:'myname',age:99,gender:'myGender'};
localStorage.setItem("user",me);
//fetch object
console.log(localStorage.getItem("user")); // will return "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use full featured Angular module [**angular-local-storage**](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

> An AngularJS module that gives you access to the browsers local
>   storage with cookie fallback

**set**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function submit(key, val) {
   return localStorageService.set(key, val);
  }
  //...
});
```

**get**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
  //...
  function getItem(key) {
   return localStorageService.get(key);
  }
  //...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

setItem wont work instead it will create another item in localStorage with the same name

Instead directly use

localStorage.item = (what ever the change that you want in the item)

Comment: localStorage.item throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.item is not a function