# How to change the value of an item in localstorage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have an object stored in localStorage.

```
let ship = {
    name: "black pearl",
    captain: "Jack Sparraw"
  };

 localStorage.setItem("ship", JSON.stringify(ship));
```

[image]

Now I want to change "name" to a new name. How to achieve it using Javascript?

(The following code does not work, but it gives an idea what I want to do)

```
 localStorage.setItem(localStorage.getItem("ship").name, "newName");
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('ship', JSON.stringify({...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ship')), name: 'newName'}))`

Comment: I added an answer for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052087/how-do-i-update-localstorage-items/58155423#58155423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You retrieve the JSON, parse it, update the object you get from parsing it, stringify the result, and store that result:

```
const ship = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ship"));
ship.name = "newName";
localStorage.setItem("ship", JSON.stringify(ship));
```

If you want to do it all in one line (although I don't recommend it, it's harder to read, maintain, and debug that way; leave minification to minifiers):

```
localStorage.setItem("ship", JSON.stringify(Object.assign(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ship")), {name: "newName"})));
```

Comment: @Ning - Thanks for catching that! *(I think your edit was rejected by the reviewers because you only fixed one place but it needed fixing in two.)*