# JavaScript function changes value of local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, storage

I am creating a website where when different functions occur in javaScript, I need to change the value of my local storage. For example here is my current code:

```
localStorage.setItem('colorvar', '#EBDBC2');
```

I need to create something where when a function occurs, the value which currently it set to #EBDBC2 will change to a value of my choice. I've tried just duplicating the line of code above and putting it in a function and changing the value but for some reason that wasn't working. Does anybody know how I can create a function where when the function runs, it will change the value in my local storage?

Comment: could you show how did you write the function?

Comment: Are you sure the function is running? Try adding a console.log to the function.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then revise your post with your attempt. Just asking for some code will surely get your question closed by the community.

Comment: See [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155249/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-item-in-localstorage-using-javascript) for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const setLocalStorageValue = (new_value) => localStorage.setItem('colorvar', new_value);
const getLocalStorageValue = () => localStorage.getItem('colorvar');

setLocalStorageValue('Value_1');
console.log(getLocalStorageValue());
setLocalStorageValue('Value_2');
console.log(getLocalStorageValue());
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5af4e6ks/15/