# How do I update/Change values in Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

[image: The first for loop updates the qty to user input]

Hi, I'm fairly new to JS and I wanted to know how I can change/update the qty for the **"inCart"** under **"productsInCart"** so that it reflects the `event.target.value` from the user.

Right now, I'm able to get the qty value from the user but unable to reflect that change to the Local Storage. Thus, when I update the site, it does not appear to change the qty.

Comment: Its a duplicate question. Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052232/4471013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a local storage variable by using `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` with your key and value. Make sure to update the value before calling `localStorage.setItem`.

Comment: I tried to call ```localStorage.setItem(item.inCart, event.target.value); ```; however, it would just create a new key and set the value to the new key created.

Comment: From what I can see of your code, it seems that you need to write to `"productsInCart"` and not `item.inCart`. I can't see all the code though, so forgive me if I'm wrong, but surely you just need to stringify `cartItems` and write to `"productsInCart"`, the same place you took the object from to start with?

Comment: I was able to do ```localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));``` and got it. Thank you!